# Error parsing JSON when sending value to discord, discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I can make the content of the json appear on console log just fine, but it's getting an error when I send it to a discord channel. The error is null: "error parsing json null"

Here's my code. FYI, I use math.random to get 1 value from an array in a json file, then I send the value to discord.

```
fs.readFile("text.json","utf-8", (err, jsonString) => {
  if(err) {
    console.log(err);
  } else {
    try {
    const data = JSON.parse(jsonString);
    const randomText = data.question[Math.floor(Math.random() * data.question.length)]; //randomizer
    console.log(randomText);
      
    client.channels.cache.get(myChannel).send(randomText); //send to discord
    }
    catch {
    console.log("Error parsing JSON!", err);
    }
  }
})
```

My text.json file

```
{
"question": ["Why?", "How?", "What?"]
}
```

Comment: So I found out the reason why it might be showing null is because the readFile is async and it might be sending it without waiting  for the async function. If so, how do I make the .send run after readfile completes? I thought putting it at bottom should do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work. I just have to put the send on an event listener like cron job or await. Thanks!